# passing a pointer value to a C function from python

Tags: python, c

I have a C function which takes a int and returns by filling up the value in b

```
typedef   uint8_t State;
#define   STATE_POWERDOWN               ((State) 0x00) 
#define   STATE_SLEEP                   ((State) 0x10) 


int Val_GetStatus(int a , State *b)
```

This function alongwith others has been exported from a C DLL.

I call this function from python. While I am able to connect with the DLL I don't understand
how to pass a variable to this function in python ?

```
def Acme_getDeviceStatus(self,DeviceStatus):
    # b 
    self.device.Val_GetStatus(0,b)  # how to pass and get value in b
    # DeviceStatus = b
    # return DeviceStatus somehow
```

Comment: How is State defined in C?

Comment: @wenzul updated with definition of State

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use for example [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-ctypes.html) or [swig](http://www.swig.org/) to call C functions in Python.

```
from ctypes import *

Val_GetStatus= CDLL('x').Val_GetStatus
Val_GetStatus.argtypes = [c_int,POINTER(c_unit8)]
Val_GetStatus.restype = c_int

deviceStatus = ctypes.c_uint8()

print Val_GetStatus(0, byref(deviceStatus))
print deviceStatus.value
```

Swig will generate kind of interface for you, so you don't have to do it manually.